# Ehcache ReentrantReadWriteLock in concurrent environment

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, caching, ehcache

I have a problem in a productive environment with Websphere 7.x with the ehcache 2.1.0 library. The threads of the web container are all waiting for consultation or insertion in a cache.

This is the dump at the moment when all webcontainer threads are pending:

```
NULL
3XMTHREADINFO      "WebContainer : 11" J9VMThread:0x00000000C7C10300, j9thread_t:0x0000010043913FB0, java/lang/Thread:0x00000000507623F0, state:P, prio=5
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:182)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:822) < 2 >
java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$WriteLock.lock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:907)
net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.Segment.put(Segment.java:402)
net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.CompoundStore.put(CompoundStore.java:132)
net.sf.ehcache.Cache.putInternal(Cache.java:1247) < 2 >
org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCache.put(EhCacheCache.java:70)
xxx.yyy.fac.security.userdetails.GaiaLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.putElementCache(GaiaLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:466) < 4 >
xxx.yyy.dgtp.gaiafrontend.core.filters.preauth.GaiaGrantedAuthoritiesWebAuthenticationDetails.buildDetails(GaiaGrantedAuthoritiesWebAuthenticationDetails.java:32) < 1 >
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doAuthenticate(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:114) < 1 >
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184) < 1 >
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) < 1 >
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:322)
xxx.yyy.dgtp.gaiafrontend.core.web.filters.JsonDeserializerFilter.doFilterChain(JsonDeserializerFilter.java:109) < 1 >
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
xxx.yyy.dgtp.gaiafrontend.core.filters.userinfo.UserInfoFilter.followWithTheRequestChain(UserInfoFilter.java:106) < 1 >
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
xxx.yyy.dgtp.gaia.commons.web.filters.RequestResponseWrapperFilter.doFilter(RequestResponseWrapperFilter.java:69)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
xxx.yyy.dgtp.gaiafrontend.core.web.filters.ResponseHeadersFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeadersFilter.java:55)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184) < 1 >
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) < 1 >
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125) < 1 >
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939) < 1 >
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3994)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453) < 3 >
com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214) < 1 >
com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1660)
```

I use spring  as an abstraction layer on ehcache and the code to get/put on the cache programmatically has nothing special.

The configuration of the cache is as follows:

```
    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cacheFactoryBean() {

        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheManagerFactoryBean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        ehCacheManagerFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("gaia-cache-ldap.xml"));
        return ehCacheManagerFactoryBean;

    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManagerLdap() {
        CacheManager cacheManager = new EhCacheCacheManager(cacheFactoryBean().getObject());
        return cacheManager;

    }
```

The code with access to the cache:

```
 private void getMemberOfRecursive(String group, ConcurrentMap<String, String> groupsCollector) {

        if (group != null) {
            if (existInCache(group)) {
                log.debug("Group: {} exist in cache. No query executing", group);
                groupsCollector.put(group, group);
                Set<String> groups = (Set<String>) getElementCache(group).get();
                for (String newGroup : groups) {
                    getMemberOfRecursive(newGroup, groupsCollector);
                }
            } else {
                String cn = getCnFromDn(group);
                String filter = MessageFormat.format(getFilterGroupRecursive(), cn);
                String baseDN = group.substring(group.indexOf(",") + 1);
                groupsCollector.put(group, group);

                log.debug("Executing recursive  query with baseDN: {} " +
                        " and filter {}: ", baseDN, filter);
                Set<String> groups =
                        getLdapTemplate().searchForSingleAttributeValues(
                                baseDN, filter, new String[]{}, getRetrievesAttributes());
                putElementCache(group, groups);
                for (String newGroup : groups) {
                    getMemberOfRecursive(newGroup, groupsCollector);
                }
            }

        }
```

Ehcache config file:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="false"    monitoring="autodetect"       dynamicConfig="true">
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />
    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="3000" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="1200"
                  timeToLiveSeconds="1200" overflowToDisk="true" maxElementsOnDisk="10000"
                  diskPersistent="false" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
                  memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>
    <cache name="groupsldap" maxElementsInMemory="3000" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>

</ehcache>
```

Comment: Can you add the Ehcache configuration ? And if possible, try upgrading to a more recent version, `2.1.0` is pretty ancient.

Comment: It is a possibility that we have but it would have to evaluate the rise of version. The goal is to really know if it is a fix of that version before performing the update.

Comment: At least one thread must be holding the lock. Or there are 2 different locks held (two different stack trace) which then can cause a deadlock. It is not possible to have all threads blocked on the same lock (and the thread dump might lie about it... they are not that reliable).

Comment: The dump may not be very reliable because it does not show any deadlock. However I do not know if the blocking can be causing ehcache to obtain a lock to manage the output of the cache of some element or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it was possible to reproduce the production error. This error appears to be related to the cross groups that existed at least in users of an Active Directory group. This error has also skipped without the cache enabled last week and to be able to analyze it more closely it was observed that there were stackoverflowerror that in this case caused the ldap connection pool to be exhausted with threads in wait state.

Once discovered that it was due to this problem and included fix that eliminates the previously visited groups, it has been reproduced in local the test this time with cache and we have to saturate the pool of threads of the web container with behavior analogous to that detected in production.